# Line size does not change for geom_sf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I stumbled on an issue that I don't fully understand. When plotting a map of Syria, I tried to increase the country's border line. However, did not respond to the `size` argument. After researching for some time, I couldn't find an alternative argument to use than `size`. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

admin0.shp <- getData('GADM', country='SYR', level=0)
#> Warning in getData("GADM", country = "SYR", level = 0): getData will be removed in a future version of raster
#> . Please use the geodata package instead
admin0.shp <- st_as_sf(admin0.shp)

ggplot(admin0.shp)+
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(admin0.shp)+
  geom_sf(size=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `linewidth` aesthetic (since `ggplot2` [v.3.4.0](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#ggplot2-340)):

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

admin0.shp <- getData('GADM', country='SYR', level=0)
#> Warning in getData("GADM", country = "SYR", level = 0): getData will be removed in a future version of raster
#> . Please use the geodata package instead
admin0.shp <- st_as_sf(admin0.shp)

ggplot(admin0.shp)+
  geom_sf(linewidth = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>